# Use of ternary operator

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I am working on a PHP project and got an error:

CODE:

```
 echo'<table>  
<td> ' .(   ($approve == 1 AND $decline == 0 )? "<span style='color: green'>  approved</span>" 
      : ($approve == 0 AND $decline == 0 )? "<span style='color: orange'>  
      Pending </span>" : "<span style='color: red'>  Declined </span>"
       ).   ' </td> </table>';
```

Is the above format for using ternary operator right? because I can not get the right value. please tell me what is the error?
edit:
the error is i can't get approved instead iam getting pending and declined.

Comment: 1) What is your Error? 2) What version of PHP? 3) What does your PHP Error log tell you? 4) What result are you expecting? 5) *Add answers to your question by **editing** your question*.

Comment: You need to switch into PHP mode? i.e. `<td> <?php (   ($approve == 1 AND $decline == 0 ) ?  ...   ?>  </td>`

Comment: as said by @RyanVincent where is the swiching between php snippets and if you do it you need echo "<some html>" to output html

Comment: actually i am only getting only pending and declined but it dosent show approved

Comment: I bet that misuse of parenthesis is the issue

Comment: You're not covering all cases: what if $decline != 0 ?

Comment: the database is a tinyint type it only has o or 1.

Comment: Nested ternaries?!? Please, just don't.... use `ifs` for readability

Comment: @MarkBaker letting people shoot themselves in the foot is sometimes the only way for them to really learn these things.... guns are dangerous.

Comment: @Mark Baker  I have tried that . But you can't write if statement in echo right?

Comment: Not directly, no.... but nested ternaries make for code that is awkward to read.... in 6 months time, if you need to change it, you'll struggle to understand what you've written..... set a variable using if statements before the echo, then just embed that variable in the echo.... code is more easily readable, more easily understood, and less prone to making mistakes when you write it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error in using "()"

```
$approve = 1;
$decline = 0;

$res = ($approve == 1 AND $decline == 0)
    ? "<span style='color: green'>  Approved</span>"
    : (
    ($approve == 0 AND $decline == 0)
        ? "<span style='color: orange'>  Pending </span>"
        : "<span style='color: red'>  Declined </span>"
    );

echo $res;
```

The third operand of the first condition must be in
parentheses.

For your code using parentheses:

```
echo '<td>'
. (($approve == 1 AND $decline == 0)
    ? "<span style='color: green'>  Approved</span>"
    : (
    ($approve == 0 AND $decline == 0)
        ? "<span style='color: orange'>  Pending </span>"
        : "<span style='color: red'>  Declined </span>"
    ))
. '</td>';
```

Comment: @ENZOAUDITORE was it a code hostage situation? *"You have 3 hours to Fix my code else you're going to **die**!*" `:-)`

Comment: LOL! no i had to present the project the next day!